# Rename file using Date Modified and incremental number

Tags: powershell

I would like to rename my files according to the Modified Date and I have been using this code:

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH.mm.ss") + ($_.Extension)}
```

The problem is that it gives me error if multiple files have the exact same Date. How can I add an incremental number to avoid the error?

Example:

| Old name | Modified Date | New Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Photo1 | 20230825 23.00.53 | 20230825 23.00.53 |
| Photo2 | 20230825 23.00.53 | 20230825 23.00.53 (1) |
| Photo3 | 20230826 02.04.10 | 20230826 02.04.10 |
| Photo4 | 20230828 18.02.20 | 20230828 18.02.20 |
| Photo5 | 20230828 18.02.20 | 20230828 18.02.20 (1) |
| Photo6 | 20230828 18.02.20 | 20230828 18.02.20 (2) |

Comment: You can group your files using `Group-Object` and the property `LastWriteTime` and iterate over all files in groups with more than one member adding an increasing counter.

Comment: Can you please write the code? I know I'm asking a lot, but I'm really new to Powershell and I don't really know how to do what you have written (my knowledge of PowerShell only extends to the code I wrote above, which was explained in a tutorial)

Comment: You can always do `dir | sort lastwritetime` just to sort them.  I do that a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it using a hashtable to store and increment processed dates:

```bash
$map = @{}
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {
    # store the date with the desired format
    $date = $_.LastWriteTime.ToString('yyyyMMdd HH.mm.ss')
    # check if exist and increment
    if ($map[$date]++) {
        # if the date exist in the hash concatenate with the index
        $date += " ($($map[$date]))"
    }
    # the new name
    $date + $_.Extension
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem -File | 
Group-Object -Property LastWriteTime |
ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Count -gt 1) {
        $Counter = 1
        foreach ($file in $_.Group) {
            $NewName = '{0}_({2}){1}' -f $file.LastWriteTime.ToString('yyyyMMdd HH.mm.ss'), $file.Extension, $Counter
            Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName $NewName -WhatIf
            $Counter++
        }
    }
    else {
        foreach ($file in $_.Group) {
            $NewName = '{0}{1}' -f $file.LastWriteTime.ToString('yyyyMMdd HH.mm.ss'), $file.Extension
            Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName $NewName -WhatIf
        }
    }
}
```

!! untested ... check and remove the `-WhatIf` if you're satisfied.

Comment: `Group-Object -Property LastWriteTime` will most likely not find any duplicates I think it should be `Group-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.ToString('yyyyMMdd HH.mm.ss') }`

Comment: It seemed to work on a test on my machine just fine.  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: That's fine ;) just note you're grouping files down to the millisecond and then renaming them down to the second...

Comment: That shouldn't matter actually since they're obviously created at the same millisecond since they're actually grouped by `Group-Object`. And if @Andrea Brama does not mind I won't either. ;-)